# How to show $x_i<x_{i-1}+\delta$?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

[image]

I'm not getting how  to show the first half of the inequality  in the yellow highlighted text.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from partition norm $\lt \delta$. That means $|x_{i-1} - x_i| \lt \delta$ which implies $x_{i} - x_{i-1} \lt \delta$

Comment: :Ooops!! I forgot this fact.Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: @PKStyles You welcome.